# Error while pulling image from docker registry

Tags: linux, docker-registry, docker-image

I am trying to pull `registry image` from docker.

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

But it gives an error like below:

`docker: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/registry/images: dial tcp 52.73.159.23:443: getsockopt: no route to host.`

I have set the proxy but it doesn't help. What could be the problem? I am running on Redhat linux 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are behind an HTTP proxy server, for example in corporate settings, you will need to add configure the `Docker systemd service` file.
First, create a `systemd` drop-in directory for the docker service:

`mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`

Now create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable:

`[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"`

Flush changes:`systemctl daemon-reload`
Restart Docker: `systemctl restart docker`

see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy for details.

Comment: @user327843 Happy to help :)